# VB6 debugging- doesn't go to error handling code

Tags: dll, vb6, activex

I'm maintaining a vb6 project(ActiveX DLL). When debugging, the app run into the following function:

```
Public Function HasValue(ByVal vValue) As Boolean

    On Error GoTo Err

    If IsMissing(vValue) Then
        HasValue = False
    ElseIf IsNull(vValue) Or Len(vValue) = 0 Then
        HasValue = False
    ElseIf isEmpty(vValue) Then
        HasValue = False
    Else
        HasValue = True
    End If

Exit Function

Err:

    If IsArray(vValue) Or IsObject(vValue) Then
        HasValue = True
    Else
        HasValue = False
    End If
End Function
```

and it stops at the line

ElseIf IsNull(vValue) Or Len(vValue) = 0 Then

vValue is a custom object, contains some properties(obviously, not null).

Although I didn't put any break point there, the app stopped there and alerted error dialog saying that "Run-time error '438': Object doesn't support this property or method".

We had error handling code but the app didn't run to error handling code. It just stopped at the line causing the error and I had to stop the application.

Do you have any idea about that?
Thank you very much.

Comment: Ho: Removing the part `Or Len(vValue) = 0` and then try.

Comment: There are a few things about this question that confuse the issue.  1. It's using `IsMissing`, but `vValue` is not declared as `Optional`. `IsMissing` is used to detect `Optional Variant` parameters that are not passed to the method.  2. Your comments say that `vValue` is an object, but the code tests it using `IsNull` and `Len`. Object references are tested with `Is Nothing`.  Was this code posted verbatim, or was it obscured?

Comment: Yes, the code was copied verbatim from the app I'm maintaining. I'm very surprised at the way the developer implemented. Anyway, please ignore the logic here. I just wonder why the app doesn't run into error handling code. Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As far as getting the popup running in the debugger, it is probably related to your "Error Trapping" settings in the IDE.  Go To Tools->Options->General and see what selected under "Error Trapping".  At first glance it seems odd that your error handler is testing the vValue in the event of an error.  It makes more sense to me based on my limited understanding of this method to move both the IsArray and IsObject conditions up into the main testing logic.  Just my 2 cents :)

Comment: You can also check the error trapping setting by right-clicking in the code window, then looking at the "Toggle" item on the popup menu.

Answer (score 0):

As far as i know vb6 does not support **boolean short evaluation** in

```
 ElseIf IsNull(vValue) Or Len(vValue) = 0 Then
```

so `Len(vValue) = 0` is executed even if `IsNull(vValue)` is true.

changing your code to

```
...
ElseIf IsNull(vValue) Then
    HasValue = False
ElseIf Len(vValue) = 0 Then
    HasValue = False
ElseIf ...
```

might solve the problem